# Try except recursion or while loop?

Tags: python, recursion, error-handling, while-loop, try-except

I am doing a python course where they suggested a try and except block in a while loop in order to keep asking for input until the condition is satisfied. Intuitively I feel it is shorter to just call the function again in the "except" block like this:

```
def exceptiontest():
    try:
        print(int(input("number 1: "))+int(input("number 2:")))
    except:
        print("a mistake happened")
        exceptiontest()

exceptiontest()
```

When asking on the forum on the course I got the reply that it is not the same. I am a bit confused now. Anyone that can clarify for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are stapling function calls on the call stack : `exceptiontest(exceptiontest(exceptiontest(exceptiontest(exceptiontest(exceptiontest(exceptiontest())))))):` if you call the function again and again. thats unneded efford and bad practice - a while loop does not need to do this because you stay in the same function.

Comment: Read: [How to ask the user for input until valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: [relevant cross-site question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Comment: Dont let errors pass silently. It's good to use: except ValueError as e: print(e).

Comment: @Patrick Artner, very useful link, thank you. I understand that it has to do with performance and the call stack. Great help!

Answer (score 5):

Calling the function in the `except` will eventually raise a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error if you keep entering bad inputs. Generally must humans won't be entering that many bad data to hit the error before they give up, but you are unnecessarily putting function calls on a stack.

A `while` loop is better since it's one function call, waiting for a valid input. IT doesn't waste any more resources than it needs.

Comment: Never underestimate the ingenuity of fools.

Comment: This makes sense. I thought it might have to do with resources but I wasn't clear on that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`while` loop, for two reasons

- it's clearer to read: *while not success, try again*
- recursion is not free. It leaves the previous function stack open. it could run out of memory (probably won't, in this case, but in principle, avoid it)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to use the `while` loop which has not yet been mentioned is that you could leverage the [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) coming with Python 3.8.

The function `add` encapsulates getting two numbers and trying to add them.

```
def add():
    'try to add two numbers from user input, return None on failure'
    x = input('number 1: ')
    y = input('number 2: ')
    try:
        return float(x) + float(y)
    except TypeError, ValueError:
        return None
```

The following `while` loop runs as long as there is no `result`.

```
while (result := add()) is None:
    print('you made a mistake, make sure to input two numbers!')

# use result
```